# multiple forms and properties

Tags: c#, forms, properties

I'm working with C# language and trying to use OOP.

I'm trying to make a registration page. On the registration windows form I send all the values entered in the textboxes (firstname, lastname, username, etc.) to a User class.

`User user = new User();
user.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;`

thats how all the properties are set.

Everything works great, but after submitting I open a new form for invoicing and payment. So I close the registration form and open the payment form. In the payment form when I try to access the values I stored earlier in the User class I can't. All the properties get reset to null for strings and 0.00 for doubles.

I tried not closing registration form to see if that works, but it still resets the properties. So I figure it has something to do with creating the new object in the payment class.

How can I store the properties from the registration form into the user class, and then access those properties from the payment form?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

[Here are some options for you](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/thiagu304/passdata05172006234318PM/passdata.aspx) to pass values between forms.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you are using a *new* instance of the User class, not the reference to the object that you initialized from the form data.  That's a traditional OOP bug.  Be sure to store that reference somewhere so you don't lose track of it.  In your own application object or the main form for example.  Could even be a static variable since there ought to be only one user.

```
User user = new User(); 
user.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
```

Note that it can never work correctly with that snippet.  The *user* variable is a local variable.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is an OOP bug. I would say it is a simple misunderstanding of the way OOP works.

Answer (score 0):

youd write some code like that:

```
    public static class UserData
{
    public static string FirstName;
    public static bool Register(string firstName)
    {
        bool success = false;
        //probably db related code here
        if (success)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

from now on, you can access user properties as UserData.FirstName
i assume there will be 1 user. if i misunderstood your question and there will be more than 1 user, you should take different approach, probably hold a static reference to List in somewhere which makes sense (even in a UserData instance class as a static field) and add the last saved UserData instance to the list on completion of registration. that way you can acess to the last added object from everywhere like UserDataList[UserDataList.Count - 1].FirstName